# Find list of PHP files without a namespace

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to find a list of PHP files in a directory that do not include a namespace. That can be derived in the codebase I'm working in by finding files that open a PHP tag, then immediately declare a class like so:

```
<?php

class Whatevs
{
    ...
```

So far, I've got this:

```
grep -Pnr -- "/\<\?php\s+class/m" lib
```

This doesn't give me any results. What command will find the results I want?

Comment: I guess you could do that with `pcregrep -M '<\?php\s+class' lib`

Comment: Or `grep -Pzl '<\?php\s+class' lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wiktor in the comments.

```
grep -Plzr '<\?php\s+class' lib
```

did the job. The flag `z` makes the difference; it tells grep to read data until it finds a null byte rather than a newline, so an entire file can be searched for a match rather than one line.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` scans each line individually, so unfortunately your `\s` won't allow it to match several lines together. I'd recommend simply searching for PHP files which don't include namespace declarations.

`grep -vl "^namespace " $(grep -lr "<\?php")`